# How to fire EthersJS *.on events?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, ethers.js

I am working on a react app with redux. I did implement thunk actions to:

1. Create a web3modal instance
2. Register a ethersjs provider
3. Register a ethersjs signer

Everything is very basic and simple.
However whenever I try to make use of the on events (doesn't matter if provider oder contract), they simply won't fire.

I have 2 files:

1. `walletSlice.ts` which will handle all the redux action and reducer logic with `@reduxjs/toolkit` .
2. `wallet-api.ts` which has all the relevant functions to interact with the wallet.

The `walletSlice.ts` relevant part looks exactly like this:

```js
export const connectWallet = createAsyncThunk(
  'web3wallet/connectWallet',
  async (arg, thunkApi) => {
    const instance = await WalletAPI.registerWalletInstance();
    provider = await WalletAPI.registerWalletProvider(instance);
    signer = await WalletAPI.registerWalletSigner(provider);
   
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
);
```

The `wallet-api.ts` relevant parts look exactly like this:

```js
import { ethers, providers } from 'ethers';
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal';

// get Web3Modal Instance
export async function registerWalletInstance(): Promise<Web3Modal> {
  const providerOptions = {};

  const web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
    providerOptions,
  });
  const instance = await web3Modal.connect();

  return Promise.resolve(instance);
}

/**
 * register Wallet provider.
 * Events on provider @see https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider--event-methods
 * Implementing the EIP-1193 Standard @see https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1193
 */
export async function registerWalletProvider(
  instance: any
): Promise<providers.JsonRpcProvider> {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(instance);

  // Subscribe to accounts change
  provider.on('accountsChanged', (accounts: string[]) => {
    console.log(accounts);
  });

  // Subscribe to chainId change
  provider.on('chainChanged', (chainId: number) => {
    console.log(chainId);
  });

  // Subscribe to provider connection
  provider.on('connect', (info: { chainId: number }) => {
    console.log(info);
  });

  // Subscribe to provider disconnection
  provider.on('disconnect', (error: { code: number; message: string }) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

  provider.on('error', (tx) => {
    // Emitted when any error occurs
    console.log({ tx });
  });

  return Promise.resolve(provider);
}

// register Wallet signer.
export async function registerWalletSigner(
  provider: providers.JsonRpcProvider
): Promise<providers.JsonRpcSigner> {
  const signer = provider.getSigner();
  return Promise.resolve(signer);
}
```

None of the `provider.on()` events will fire. I've tried to change networks from `rinkeby` to `polygon` or `mainnet`, but nothing happens. When I disconnect from the site, nothing happens. It is the same with all provider events as shown in `wallet-api.ts`. I did try the same approach with another file called `contract-api.ts`. However the contract events won't fire either.

I tried to use the `provider.on()` events with `useEffect()` or `useCallback()`. Moved the code to a standalone tsx. But nothing happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`await web3Modal.connect()` already returns a provider;
try to use that one instead of `new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(instance);`

Comment: This solved it. Using the instance to register the events did the trick. I will look into the contract api and see if there is a solution like this one. Thanks Mike!